# memoir manual: Figure 2.13 Errata

Tags: memoir

The caption for Figure 2.13 (v3.7.19, 2022/11/17) on page 34 contains

> The outer fra indicate the stock size.

which most likely should be

> The outer frames indicate the stock size.

Is this correct?

Comment: +1. You may also want to contact the maintainer of the `memoir` bundle -- Lars Madsen (email: daleif at math dot au dot dk) -- directly to point out this issue to him.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. Please contact the maintainer, Lars Madsen, as noted in the documentation.

Comment: Will do. (For some reason I don't remember, I didn't contact Lars directly.)

Comment: Fixed in devel version. Thanks for the report

Comment: No, thank you for maintaining 'memoir'. There's nothing else like it.